# Variable not accepting value

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Boolean **control_refresh** in class A and in a class that inheres A i have a function in which is control_refresh=true;. The code compiles fine.

file_1.cs

```
public partial class graficki_editor : Form
{
    ...
    internal bool control_refresh = false;
    ...
}
```

file_3.cs

```
public partial class graficki_editor : Form
{
    ...
    private void canvas_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        debug_label.Text = control_refresh.ToString();
    }
    ...
}
```

file_2.cs

```
internal class projekt : graficki_editor
{
    ...
    private void sloj_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
                objekti.ElementAt(pan.Controls.IndexOf(((CheckBox)sender).Parent)).visible = true;
        else objekti.ElementAt(pan.Controls.IndexOf(((CheckBox)sender).Parent)).visible = false;

        control_refresh = true;
        canvas.Refresh();
    }
    ....
}
```

(Non relevant code is excluded)

In the scope of **sloj_Checked** I can set **control_refresh** and in than scope it works fine. But when the control is refreshed and paint event is called the variable stays the same.

My question is how do I change the variable?

By the request of Scott Chamberlain:

```
static void Main()
{
    ...
    Application.Run(new graficki_editor());
}

public partial class graficki_editor : Form
{
    ...
    public void novaSlika(int sirina, int visina, string ime, Color odabir)
    {  
        projekt nova = new projekt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Your code [will not compile](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k1PlXk), please use a site like Dot Net Fiddle to make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: An internal class cannot inherit from it's parent.

Comment: I apologize. I was trying to summarize my code. But I didn't test it. Edited now.

Comment: Running B's constructor prints `true`, not `false`, as you claim, as one would expect.

Comment: @AntonioKovačević review the following code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nOBQ5Q

Comment: Hmm seems that I'll have to elaborate better. I'll edit my question in a minute.

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope you guys understand what I'm asking.

Comment: Please include in your question how you are calling the constructor for `graficki_editor` and/or `projekt`

Answer (score 0):

You should call [Control.Invalidate Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a(v=vs.110).aspx) **in sloj_Checked** method

```
// canvas.Refresh(); // do not call refresh
canvas.Invalidate();
```

Comment: I didn't know about Invalidate. Thank you. Do You perhaps have any ideas about my current predicament?

Answer (score 0):

in

```
public void novaSlika(int sirina, int visina, string ime, Color odabir)
{  
    projekt nova = new projekt();
}
```

You are creating a 2nd form, its is a entirely separate window, you just never call `nova.Show()` to see it. That is why when you change `nova` properties in the parent form `graficki_editor` don't get changed.

Comment: It is shown in the TabControl. Each new instance of `project` gets added to the TabControl I'll post a link to my project. Relevant lines.  `Variables: line 33`, `Classes: line 311`, `graficki_editor: line 29`  [link]removed
note: this is my first project for collage and it's made in a rush so I apologize for the bad code organisation. And some of the names are in my language (Croatian) but I'm sure You can understand it.

Comment: Please update your question with the smallest possible compilable program that demonstrates your issue. I will not download projects from external websites on SO, I only will copy and paste code that is posted in questions only. Sorry.

Comment: I was unable to replicate the problem. The only solution I found is to nest the class `projekt` in `graficki_editor` and make `control_refresh` static . Thanks for  Your help.